# Can I use extern to semi-reference other .net assemblies?

Tags: .net, dllimport

I have a project that I want to have 99% of the functionality not reference a dll.
I don't want to have to have that `dll` to use/build (and build server build) the rest of the code.

Language is irrelevant (I can handle all the .net languages).

Can I declare `extern` functions that point to managed .net dlls?

Comment: `extern` is not useful.  You can shoot your leg off with Reflection, start that with Activator.CreateInstance() to create the object.  You need to use the [full type name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/specifying-fully-qualified-type-names) so the CLR can locate the appropriate dll file.

Comment: Maybe you can at least declare an interface and actually meant to support plug-ins.  Googling ".net plugin framework" is then a good bet.